# Is it safe to check for empty value direct in query using php?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a password recovery system with expire time.

Querying like in example bellow when user click to url in their email:

```
SELECT * FROM PassReset WHERE selector = ? AND token = ? AND token <>"" AND tokenExpire >= NOW()
```

if not execute display error, Looks like it works fine on itself without any validating like if statement.

I want to know if is safe to check for empty (not null) values direct in the query and do I need more validating if it executes?

Comment: In what sense would it be unsafe to check for an empty value in SQL?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, check for empty values from mysql direct in query is it enough or do I need more valitaion for expire time or empty value etc.

Comment: @Dharman using "" etc.  and do I need to do more validation for emty or expire values ?

Comment: "empty" values are no different from any other values. you can use them in any conditions just like any other value

Comment: *`.. token = ? AND token <>"" ..`* If you do not provide empty string like a parameter value then 2nd condition is excess. And if you may provide this then this condition is excess again.